# Can't access property generated by a script in an imported ANT target

Tags: javascript, apache, ant, properties

What I'm trying to do is compile to a file which takes it's version from a constant inside my source files.

I have a setup like this (or at least the significant bits):

tasks/compile.xml

```
<project name="Compile">
    <target name="check.version">
        <script language="javascript">
            regex = /VERSION.+?"([\d\.]+)";/;
            r = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(new java.io.File(file)));
            line = r.readLine();
            while ( (line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                m = regex.exec(line);
                if (m) {
                    project.setProperty( "project.version" , m[1] );
                    break;
                }
            }
            r.close();
        </script>
        <echo>${ant.project.name}-${project.version}</echo> <!-- = Fail-0.2 -->
    </target>
</project>
```

And a build.xml:

```
<project name="Fail"> 
    <import file="${basedir}/build/tasks/compile.xml"/>

    <target name="test">
        <antcall target="check.version">
            <param name="file" value="${basedir}/Source.as"/>
        </antcall>
        <echo>${project.version}</echo> <!-- = ${project.version} -->
        <echoproperties></echoproperties>
    </target>
</project>
```

So, it seems that the property set by the script is only locally defined in that target, if i specify another target in the same project ("Compile") it won't know of that property either.

I've also tried to set a  in the "Compile"-project xml but it won't be overwritten by the target anyway.

So how can I access that property generated by the script? Or is there another way for doing something like this?

I'd really like to keep that part in a separate xml as it makes the project build script so much cleaner.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, do you know of any IRC channels (with people in it) for ant related questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the other target via `antcall`, properties set within it won't be in the scope of the caller.

If you need to access properties set by another target, you could declare that target as a dependency to ensure that it gets executed before your target. Like this:

```
<target name="test" depends="check.version">
    <echo>${project.version}</echo> <!-- = value set in check.version -->
    <echoproperties></echoproperties>
</target>
```

---

**Edit:** There's also the [AntCallBack](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/antcallback_task.html) task which is available from [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) and [Antelope](http://antelope.tigris.org/):

> AntCallBack is identical to the
>   standard 'antcall' task, except that
>   it allows properties set in the called
>   target to be available in the calling
>   target.

Comment: Excellent! But as I can't pass a parameter into a depends (or can I?) I simply look for a property then. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer to add a mention of `antcallback` task from Ant-Contrib.